# How automatically remove callback from callbacks Array, when it has not caller any more?

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-management, callback, release

I have these classes:

```
class Callback {
    let callback: () -> Void
    init(callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
    }
}

class CallbackContainer {
    private var callBacks = [Callback]()
    
    func add(callback: @escaping () -> Void) -> Callback {
        let cl = Callback(callback: callback)
        callBacks.append(cl)
        return cl
    }
    
    func callAll() {
        for callback in callBacks {
            callback.callback()
        }
    }
}

class Container {
    let callbackContainer = CallbackContainer()
    
    func executeSomeLongTasks() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {[weak self] in
            self?.callbackContainer.callAll()
        }
    }
}

class AViewController: UIViewController {
    var callback: Callback?
    let container: CallbackContainer
    init(container: CallbackContainer) {
        self.container = container
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callback = container.add {
            debugPrint("Called callback on A")
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        debugPrint("Deinited AViewController")
    }
}
```

I want the `CallbackContainer` to remove the callbacks automatically when nobody is calling them any more. For example:

```
let container = Container()

var aVC: AViewController? = AViewController(container: container.callbackContainer)

//on somewhere executed long task
container.executeSomeLongTasks()
aVC = nil
// should not call callback here
```

Here, when `aVC` is released - like `aVC = nil` or popping it  from navigation stack - then the callback stored in `callbackContainer` (created on `AViewController viewDidload()`), should be removed from the internal array automatically, without the need of removing it on `AViewController deinit()` manually. Hence, the callback will not be called any more from `CallbackContainer.callAll()`

It should work like the `DisposeBag` on `RxSwift`. I saw `DisposeBag` code, but did not understand.

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a kind of *weak array*. As far as I know, there is no such type in the Swift foundation classes: My first thought was to use `NSMapTable` or something similar with `weakToStrongObjects` configuration, which is documented to store the keys as weak references, but unfortunately that class does not reorganize itself automatically, see the [discussion part](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable/1391346-weaktostrongobjects):

> Use of weak-to-strong map tables is not recommended. The strong values for weak keys   > which get zeroed out continue to be maintained until the map table resizes itself.

What you could do is:

- Create a boxing object that stores a weak reference and the closure
- Add that box into the `callBacks` array.
- When calling `callAll`, first clean up the `callBacks` array to remove all boxes with `nil` references.

That manual cleanup is a drawback, because you will not be informed when a weak reference is `nil`-led by ARC. But it is done centrally by the Container, so the clients do not need to take care.

For example:

```
typealias CallbackType = () -> Void

class WeakCallback : Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    weak var refItem: AnyObject?
    let callback:CallbackType
    
    init(refItem: AnyObject, callback:@escaping CallbackType) {
        self.refItem = refItem
        self.callback = callback
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: WeakCallback, rhs: WeakCallback) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}


class CallbackContainer {
    var callBacks = [WeakCallback]()
    
    func add(ref:AnyObject, callback: @escaping () -> Void) -> WeakCallback {
        cleanupCallbackArray()
        let cl = WeakCallback(refItem:ref, callback: callback)
        callBacks.append(cl)
        return cl
    }
    
    func callAll() {
        cleanupCallbackArray()
        for cb in callBacks {
            if (cb.refItem != nil) {
                cb.callback()
            } else {
                print ("oops, found nil for \(cb.id)")
            }
        }
    }
    func cleanupCallbackArray() {
        callBacks = callBacks.filter { cb -> Bool in
            if (cb.refItem == nil) {
                print ("\(cb.id) has nil reference, will be removed")
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in `viewDidLoad`, add the view controller as a reference to the container:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        callback = container.add (ref:self) {
            debugPrint("Called callback on A")
        }
    }
```

To test:

```
let cbContainer = CallbackContainer()

var aVC: AViewController? = AViewController(container: cbContainer)
aVC?.viewDidLoad()
print ("callAll 1")
cbContainer.callAll()
print ("set to nil")
aVC = nil
print ("callAll 2")
cbContainer.callAll()
```

gives:

> callAll 1
>
> "Called callback on A"
>
> set to nil
>
> "Deinited AViewController"
>
> callAll 2
>
> 81C3D375-4B0E-4806-8088-AFE81C3125F3 has nil reference, will be removed

As you can see, the closure will not be called upon "callAll 2".